# what is the possible reason of facebook login in magento website redirect to blank page?

Tags: php, facebook, magento

I installed an facebook login extension named inchoo.First time it runs perfect in localhost,ie. i logged in through it into my magento website successfully.Then after, two issues are coming :-

1.After login in facebbok in my website, i logged in succesfully but my name is not showing in home page.But it is showing in other pages of website.

2.And sometimes, after login it shows a blank page.

I tried it in my live website, but it is creating same problem there also.

I need any help.I will be very thankful to any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you get a blank page on your magento installation then it means a php error behind a scene. By default error reporting is disabled for Magento in index.php so to get the real cause behind this:

1. enable error logging from index.php `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
2. inspect your server php error log

do all that and you can ask a better question and maybe answer the question before you ask.